# Java Swing add component for game

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm writing a game in Java swing, and have a few layers of classes that I need to implement.

Here are the classes:

- Main() //Sets up window, makes a Game, and setVisible

  - Game() //Draws main game canvas, maintains data about the game, tells each object to draw itself

    - Board() //Draws the rooms and background graphics

      - Room() //Draws the stuff inside the room, keeps track of location

        - Items() //Location, color, function, etc

          - CollectibleItems() //extends Items
          - Creatures() //extends Items
    - ControlPanel() //Put a button in that does something
    - StatePanel() //Put text in the panel of the room, and whether or not its locked

Main class:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Main ();
    }

    public Main () {
        // Window setup                                                                            
        setSize (700, 450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        // Put a Game in                                                                        
        Game myGame=new Game ();    
        myGame.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 9));
        content.add(myGame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            setVisible (true);
    }
```

This is my Game class. From here I want to add the Board and Panels, and I want the Board to add the Rooms, etc. I don't know how to encapsulate classes and still add them and setVisible. I know how to do it within main, but is there a way to add stuff to Game using a similar content.add() type of thing?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Game extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

        JPanel ControlPanel=new JPanel();
        ControlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ControlPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 9));
    }
}
```

TL;DR- how do I encapsulate and display different classes? New to JavaSwing...

Answer (score 3):

To start with...DON'T DO THIS!! EVER!!

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

    JPanel ControlPanel=new JPanel();
    ControlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ControlPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 9));
}
```

Also you MUST call `super.paintComponent` as well, unless you have a REALLY, REALLY good reason not to.  These methods do a lot of important background work.

Never modify any component from within the context of the any `paintXxx` method.  This will put you into an infinite loop and eventually consuming all you CPU.

I would start by having a read through

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)